# Dictionary Index of dictionary contained in a list in Django template

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Im trying to print all dictionaries which are contained in a list into a list in a Django template.
Its in JSON form from [https://data.dublinked.ie/cgi-bin/rtpi/realtimebusinformation?stopid=184&format=json ] I have

```
<ul>
{% for key, value in results.0.items %}
<li>{{key}} {{value}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

in my template which outputs the first dictionary at position 0 from the list. The amount of dictionaries in the list is always changing so I'm looking to have them all printed depending on how many are in the list.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sound like you need to add another loop `{% for result in results %}`. Then you can loop through `result.items` in the inner loop:

```
<ul>
  {% for result in results %}
    {% for key, value in result.items %}
      <li>{{key}} {{value}}</li>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks that works I just need each dictionary in a different list.

Comment: If you want each dictionary in a different list, then swap the `ul` and outer `for` tags.